# Blinking Cursor on Bash Script

Tags: bash

I was working on 1 bash script, where I have to wait for command to get completed.

I was looking if we can display blinking cursor until the command is completed in Bash script?

I saw there are some progress bar scripts already present here, but looking for something which can just blink and show terminal is still live.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Cursor blinking is controlled by the terminal itself, not by your script. Blinking doesn't mean your script is alive, it means you have set up blinking at some point. You need to output something periodically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See following example:

```
$ cat blink.sh
#!/bin/bash

printf 'Working'
for ((i = 0; i < 5; ++i)); do
    for ((j = 0; j < 4; ++j)); do
        printf .
        sleep 5
    done

    printf '\b\b\b\b    \b\b\b\b'
done
printf '....done\n'
$
```

This is how it looks like when running:

[image]

Comment: Thanks looks great. How to integrate with command, so that it stops when command is finished.

Comment: just check some condition in the for loop. how do u manually check if the command is finished?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `blink` attribute

```
printf "$(tput blink)"
sleep 30
tput sgr0
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting.
I tried on terminal, but it keeps on blinking.